# NET8 MAUI building error for iOS: was built for newer iOS Simulator version (14.5) than being linked

Tags: c#, ios, maui

In my `NET8` `MAUI`, I use the component [MauiMTAdmob](https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob). I say that because I think the error is related to *Google Mobile Ads*. When I deploy the application to the Apple simulator, I get this error

> ld: warning: object file
> (/Users/enrico/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/LanguageInUse/1fa03704bb15e35c6f47a701d9d92131e3e0740198296a93338bb3c829bc9cf7/C:/Users/enric/AppData/Local/XamarinBuildDownloadCache/FAdM-8.13.0/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADGestureMock.o))
> was built for newer iOS Simulator version (14.5) than being linked
> (14.0) ld: warning: object file
> (/Users/enrico/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/LanguageInUse/1fa03704bb15e35c6f47a701d9d92131e3e0740198296a93338bb3c829bc9cf7/C:/Users/enric/AppData/Local/XamarinBuildDownloadCache/FAdM-8.13.0/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAdsFramework-Current/GoogleMobileAds.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADGestureRecognizerMock.o))
> was built for newer iOS Simulator version (14.5) than being linked
> (14.0) ld: in
> /Users/enrico/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/LanguageInUse/1fa03704bb15e35c6f47a701d9d92131e3 LanguageInUse   C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets 1559

In the *Info.plist*, I set as a target the version 14.

[image]

And I do the same in the project settings.

[image]